# Select parent div and not the child div in Robot Framework

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, robotframework

I am a newbie and I am developing a test automation in Robot Framework and it needs to select the parent div but the child div is the one  that is always click.

this is my RF code:

```
Wait and click element          xpath: //div[contains(@class,'parent') and .='orange']
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   orange
</div>
```

I want TA not to click the div.child. Is there any way to do this?

div.class width is 400px and div.child width is 355px. Everytime I try to click xpath: //div[contains(@class,'parent') and .='orange'], it always click div.child

Comment: Do you wish to click on `orange` ?

Comment: yes but the hit area of div.child is big and it occupies half of the word orange.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Wait and click element          xpath://*[contains(text(),'orange')]
```

Comment: same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Use [Execute Javascript](https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript)

```
Execute Javascript  $('.parent').click()
```

update your loctors based on your requirements.

Comment: same thing happens

Comment: can you update the error logs, with trials along with execute javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **xpath axes** - An axis represents a relationship to the context (current) node, and is used to locate nodes relative to that node on the tree.

```
Wait and click element    xpath://div[contains(text(),'orange')]//parent::div
```